# How does json determine write/output order

Tags: python, json

Playing with json in Python's STL and came up with this..

```
import json as j

cred = j.dumps({'Name': 'John Doe', 'Occupation': 'Programmer'},
            sort_keys = True,
            indent = 4,
            separators = (',', ': '))

_f = open('credentials', 'w')
_f.write(cred)
_f.close()
```

The output is below and all is fine..

> {
>
> ```
>   "Name": "John Doe",
>   "Occupation": "Programmer"
> ```
>
> }

*However*, i accidentally typed name in lowercase like this..

```
cred = j.dumps({'name': 'John Doe', 'Occupation': 'Programmer'},
            sort_keys = True,
            indent = 4,
            separators = (',', ': '))
```

and the result was this..

> {
>
> ```
>   "Occupation": "Programmer",
>   "name": "John Doe"
> ```
>
> }

How does json determine the write/output order of the values passed to it, what precedence does uppercase have over lowercase or vice versa and is there a way to preserve order?

Comment: I've not looked at the source code, but I'm assuming that it sorts based on the ASCII code. [Link.](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif) You'll note that O is 79, but n is 110.

Comment: That's an invalid assumption. The order is based on a hash function, which are functions related to random number generation. It's essentially random.

Comment: @Keith Nonsense. Order in a hash table is non-deterministic. That's almost, but not quite, entirely unlike random order. While recent CPython versions actually do add some "randomization" unless explicitly disabled (in an effort to guard against a class of DOS attacks), that doesn't make the two concepts related. And what's this with RNGs? No hash function I'm aware of is in any way related to those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python dictionaries, as well as JSON objects, do not have an order. Any order you might see is arbitrary and may change at any time. If you want to store order in JSON, you'll need to use an array instead of an object.

`sort_keys` seems to guarantee some sort of output order, but that's likely only to make it more readable for humans. Computers reading JSON shouldn't care about field order.

Comment: Relatedly, if you want to preserve order in dictionaries when not using json, you should use [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).